# AngularJS - dynamically created ngmodel cannot be set from controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am working on code where user selects an item from dropdown list and the UI elements are displayed according to that selected item. Example: if item1 is selected there will be 2 textboxes, 1 textarea and a checkbox. item2 will have 1 textbox. etc.

So, I currently have a function where I add html elements according to item selected. I get a JSON file where there is list of items and what UI elements are required for that item. When user selects an item I get the required information from that JSON file and call following code:

```
  $scope.myHTML = "";
  var aForm = (angular.element(document.getElementById('appType')));
  aForm.html(''); 
  dropdown.forEach(function(viewItem, index){
    if(viewItem.control_type === "TextBox"){
     $scope.myHTML += '<label class="label">'+ viewItem.label +'</label>'+
     '<input type="text" ng-model = "item.value'+index + '" placeholder = "'+ viewItem.text +'">';
    }
    if(viewItem.control_type === "TextArea"){
     $scope.myHTML += '<label class="label">'+ viewItem.label +'</label>'+
     '<textarea type="text" rows="4" ng-model = "tests.value'+index + '" ></textarea>'';
    }
  }
  aForm.append($scope.myHTML);
  $compile(aForm)($scope);
```

So the ng-model will have item.value0,item.value1 and so on for each element. I have used $compile to add the html view to UI.

The problem is that I can get the values in my controller but I cannot set those values from controller.

```
   dropdown.forEach(function(viewItem, index){
     $scope.tests['value'+index] = "SomePresetValue";    //Does not update value on HTML
     });
```

Does not set value to the HTML element. I tried the following after searching for alternate solutions but did not work.

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
                dropdown.forEach(function(viewItem, index){
                            $scope.item['value'+index] = viewItem.value;
                        });
            });
```

Comment: Create a plunker demo that reproduces problem. Also provide all relevant code

Comment: @charlietfl I will add the plnkr link. Did you get basic idea of what I am trying to do here (I just edited question to add more info)? Thanks!

Comment: Approach is all wrong. Should be updating your data model and let angular generate the dom using things like `ng-repeat`. Almost never need to search the dom and append yourself

Comment: But I have textbox, textarea, checkbox intermingled and their sequence is not fixed. i.e. I can have textbox, then textarea, then textbox. Can this be achieved using ng-repeat?

Comment: Sure...wrap in outer wrapper and add any additional conditional logic needed within each repeat